# How to use transition with display

Tags: html, css

I want the `display:block` to fade in

HTML:

```
<div>Fade</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{display:none;transition:2s;}
div:hover{display:block;}
```

Somehow it doesnt work , is there any other way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transition the `display` property. Instead you should transition the `opacity` property.

The underlying reason for this has to do with the browsers rendering pipeline. It needs to properly layout the page before transitioning and an element with 1display: none;` has no layout (thus cannot be transitioned).

Comment: And if you want to also toggle the `display` property, you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: @JosiahKeller can i use javascript to add transition to display?

Comment: Please search for duplicates before posting an answer. There are plenty of answers on the duplicate, including one that mentions opacity. Thanks!

Comment: @MohitBhasi No, what you can do is use JavaScript to set display and then set a class so that opacity transitions.

Comment: @MohitBhasi @JosiahKeller Actually using pure css with the `:hover` pseudo selector works just fine.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Truth.

Comment: @thedeeno technically it still takes up space in the dom though so opacity achieves the same effect but may not be the intended ux. if we reaaaalllly wanted to be picky

Comment: @Daemedeor when the element is set to `display:none` it doesn't take up space. When it's `display:block; opacity:0;` it does. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @thedeeno yes, that's my point about you suggesting opacity alone so he can't just use "pure" css because he'll have to set the display none after the opacity transitions to 0